# ¿Como puedo añadir información extra en una CNN en keras?

Tags: python, redes-neuronales, keras

tengo una CNN hecha en keras (python). El código es:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=1,
                 input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 3), strides=(1, 3)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), padding='valid', strides=1,
          input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 3), strides=(1, 3)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adadelta',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Coge bien las matrices de entrada, en este caso histogramas pero me gustaría añadirle información extra como el género (variable binaria de la persona a la que pertenece), la edad (numérica) o incluso un vector fila de la misma longitud que el ancho de las matrices que entran ahora a la CNN. Cada matriz del conjunto de entrenamiento, y test, tendría una info diferente asociada.

¿Hay alguna forma de pasar esta información externa al modelo para que la procese?
No sé como buscar esta información tan concreta.

Gacias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se hace en estos casos es crear una red paralela a la CNN que reciba como entrada estos datos numéricos y en la parte final en las capas fully-connected realizar una concatenación de las representaciones de ambas redes.

Un tutorial muy completo fue escrito por Adrian Rosebrok en este [enlace](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/) que puedes usar como guía.

**Importante:** Esto no se puede hacer con la api secuencial de keras, tienes que usar la api *funcional*